How to implement route constraints in next.js
I have routes in my next.js application to show newsletters.
/newsletter shows a list of all newsletters.
/newsletter/[number] shows the newsletter issue with number=[whatever the number is].
Now I want to add a new route /newsletter/latest, which always shows the most recent one. (This is a handy permalink for showing that latest issue, instead of hardcoding a number that will shortly be out of date.)
number is always an integer, so it can be easily distinguished. However, /newsletter/latest is handled by the /newsletter/[number] route, because it doesn't know that [number] has to be an integer.
What I want is a pattern with a route constraint like /newsletter/[number:\d+], as you can do in ASP.NET, that says use this handler only if number is an integer, and then a url like /newsletter/latest will NOT be routed to the wrong place.
How can I accomplish this?

You can create a new folder called "latest" which will not act as a slug. Next.js will recognize it as a route, allowing you to structure and implement any functionality you need within that page.
